# FCR Calculation for Number of calls vs Y / N responses

Tags: excel-formula

I'm currently looking at a way to calculate FCR data.

The goal is for the formula to look at what name is in column A, and then to see how many calls are made in B that either match Y or N and then the calculate it as an average in column F.

I've put a mock up of what the data looks like when entered and also in E and F where i'd like the actual outcome to be presented.

I've been trying to work with a Sumif/Countif this morning and have not been able to get it off the ground, any support would be great and i can also then use it for future learning.

do you guys think this is possible?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mepH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Office365 you could use the following in `E2`:
`=UNIQUE(A2:A9)`
This spills the unique names.

In `F2` you can than use a SUMIFS referencing the data and the spill:
`=SUMIFS(B2:B9,C2:C9,"Y",A2:A9,E2#)/SUMIFS(B2:B9,A2:A9,E2#)`
(Format these as percentage)

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much this is amazing, took a bit for me to get it working between sheets but know it's working amazingly <3.

Comment: Just remember `#` behind a range references the spill